# Extracting year from a column that contains dates in m/d/yyyy format

Tags: r, excel, date

I have a dataset called `verts` imported from Excel with a column called `Date` that contains dates in this format: `m/d/yyyy`. I'm trying to extract the year from this column.

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```r
verts$Date_converted <- strptime(verts$Date, format = "%m-%d-%y")   
verts$Year <- format(verts$Date_converted, "%y")
```

This produced two new columns in R, as you can see in the image, but both columns only contain `NA`.

[image: my excel data in R with the two new columns I tried to convert to "Date" form and filter for year]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your date contains "/" and not "-" also you have a 4 digit year thus "%Y". `format = "%m/%d/%Y"`

Comment: I will try that, thank you so much. Very much a beginner at this.

Comment: That worked!! Many thanks. Any suggestions on how to go about nesting the grouping I need to do between characters and the numeric year? I know how to group just those two but I am struggling to filter out just Caudata from the Order column.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions here to search for.  See the group_by function in the dplyr package, that could be a good starting point.

Comment: dplyr is what I was starting to play with so I'll continue down that path - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using package `lubridate` for dates - it makes everything so much easier.

- `mdy()` quickly parses a date that's written in the US format - regardless of delimiter type.
- `year()` extracts the year from an object in date format.

```r
verts <- data.frame(Date = c("6/8/2004", "6/14/2004", "7/7/2006"))

verts <- verts |> 
  dplyr::mutate(Date_converted = lubridate::mdy(Date),
                year = lubridate::year(Date_converted))

verts
#>        Date Date_converted year
#> 1  6/8/2004     2004-06-08 2004
#> 2 6/14/2004     2004-06-14 2004
#> 3  7/7/2006     2006-07-07 2006
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

PS please don't use screenshots for data - we can't import that into R. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it more likely for you to get help.